# How can I upload and download files with graphene-django?

Tags: django, graphql, file-transfer, graphene-python, graphene-django

I'm currently using graphene-django v2.0 and I've absolutely no clue of how can I upload and download files like images, does anyone have an example of a query where you can download an Image and a mutation where you can upload one?

Comment: There is a package called graphene-file-upload, github: https://github.com/lmcgartland/graphene-file-upload which should do the work for you. I have not been able to make it work yet, but give it a try. It could be useful with a working implementation example.

Answer (score 23):

**UPLOADS**

You don't need to invent your own frontend code to add a file upload to a mutation -- there are existing packages that do this already.  For example, [apollo-upload-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-upload-client) if you are using Apollo.

To receive an uploaded file on the backend, the files are going to be available in the dictionary `request.FILES`.  So any mutation handling a file upload needs to examine `info.context.FILES.items` to get and save the file data.  The specifics of this code are going to depend on the ultimate destination of the saved file.

*(UPDATE)* However, if possible I would recommend *not* using graphene-django to upload files because it adds a large amount of complexity on both the backend and the frontend.  My team ultimately scrapped our working graphene-django file upload code and replaced it with a [standard Django file upload](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/file-uploads/).

**DOWNLOADS**

For downloads, I would recommend *not* using graphQL for the actual download.  Instead create a Django function view that returns a `HttpResponse` or `FileResponse` and sets the Content-Disposition header.  Something like

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def download(request):
    ... do stuff to get file contents and file name and mime_type
    response = HttpResponse(file_contents, content_type=mime_type)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{}"'.format(file_name)
    return response
```

Then add this download path to your `urls.py` and to a graphQL query response.  So graphQL would be used to get the download path, but actually downloading the file would be a regular Django page.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your last two sentences? I'm not sure how graphQL and `urls.py` interact together at all...

Comment: In this case, I'm talking about a normal Django flow that doesn't use graphQL -- so you'd edit urls.py to route to the download view in the normal Django way.

Comment: Thanks, I think I am starting to figure it out :D
By the way, how do you pass the address in the query? in my work, we have different environments (local-api.address.com/8000, test-api.address.com, api.address.com, etc), do you know how to get the right one from django?