# how to save file in graphene-django

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-django

I need to upload files on Django project with Graphene, but files can not be saved to the space.
I am using Digitalocean space to store files, if i upload any file via Django Admin Panel, i can see the file on the space but my below mutation function is missed. I can see the file name on the database but the file is not saved to the storage area.

What function should i add to save file i can not find any way.

Thanks in advance

```
class UploadImage(relay.ClientIDMutation):
    class Input:
        name = graphene.String(required=True)

    new_image = graphene.Field(ImageNode)

    @classmethod
    def mutate_and_get_payload(cls, root, info, **input):
        image = Image()
        check_and_set_field(input, image, "name")
        image.save()

        uploaded_img = info.context.FILES
        
        return UploadImage(new_image=image)
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49503756/how-can-i-upload-and-download-files-with-graphene-django/49516843#49516843