# How to take file input graphene-django

Tags: graphene-django

#### Graphql Mutations

```py
class UploadMutation(graphene.Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        file = Upload(required=True)

    success = graphene.Boolean()

    def mutate(self, info, file, **kwargs):
        if not file.endswith('.xlsx'):
            raise GraphQLError('File formate should be "xlsx".')
        return UploadMutation(success=True)


class FileUploadMutation(graphene.ObjectType):
    upload_file = UploadMutation.Field()
```

- I'm using below GraphQL mutations But I'm unable to upload files

```
mutation UploadFile{
  uploadFile(file: xxx){
    success
  }
}
```

Please Help me out

Comment: You have to pass file object to the request. This example could be helpful: https://github.com/lmcgartland/graphene-file-upload/blob/master/tests/test_flask.py

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49503756/how-can-i-upload-and-download-files-with-graphene-django  or the many answers here https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=graphene+upload+file